# WebStorm react-native project missing xcworkspace

Tags: react-native, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm to make the project. After setting up the project I found that I don't have `xcworkspace` file under IOS folder.

How should I generate a `xcworkspace` file?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you really need `xcworkspace` folder - you should use `react-native init`. That way your project will contain Android and iOS folders with corresponding files.
   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#creating-a-new-application
2. If you just need to initialize app - be sure that you created your app following all steps in documentation.
   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html